# Crear Aplicación Web con Java en Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy comenzando en el mundo de la programación, quiero crear una aplicación web, ¿Me pregunto si será posible usando Eclipse? pues, ya lo intenté pero no aparece la opción dentro de la plataforma del IDE Eclipse

Comment: Si se puede, instalaste todos los componentes?

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Échale un vistazo a esta página de descargas oficial, y bájate la versión para desarrollo en Java: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ Hay otras versiones para JavaScript, C++, PHP, etc.